# Plains natives happen across a late 1890s airbase

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alternate-history

Long ago I read an anthology whose introduction to one story seemed to claim it was the first of its sort. Reading over the Wiki article on alternative history, this appears to be very much *not* the case, as it is not mentioned, and most of the examples given are older than I suspect this one is.

In the story, a band of Native Americans living in the Midwest begin to see what they believe is the Thunderbird. When it returns on several occasions, they follow it and end up coming across an airbase, where the pilots of the steam-turbine aircraft are amused by their "backwardness".

Some of the band members become pilots, and at the end, written later, it is revealed that one of the aircraft is now in an aviation museum as its pilot became rather famous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Custer’s Last Jump](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93681) by Steven Utley and Howard Waldrop. I read it in [Universe 6](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?52862) edited by Terry Carr.

The story starts:

> Its wings still hold the tears from many bullets. The ailerons are still scorched black, and the exploded Henry machine rifle is bent awkwardly in its blast port. The right landing skid is missing, and the frame has been restraightened. It stands in the left wing of the Air Museum today, next to the French Devre jet and the X-FU-5 Flying Flapjack, the world’s fastest fighter aircraft. On its rudder is the swastika, an ugly reminder of days of glory fifty years ago. A simple plaque describes the aircraft. It reads:
>
> CRAZY HORSE’S KRUPP MONOPLANE (Captured at the raid on Fort Carson, January 5, 1882)

Comment: Ahhh, and as it seems several other answers ended with Universe 7, I must have had a collection of these at some time.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz as a spotty youth in the 1970s I loved those anthologies and others like them :-) I have almost all of them up to Universe 15 with just a couple missing.